# Getting wrong value with timestamp diff

Tags: mysql

i have 2 fields that are DAYTIME types, when i use the function timestampdiff(t1,t2) it returns a wrong value, here goes the example:

```
timestampdiff(SECOND, t.wfStartTimestamp, t.wfEndTimeStamp)
```

(those 2 fields are actually daytime)

returns 89734 when it should return 15, any suggestions?

Comment: 89734 looks correct to me

Comment: Why do you think you should get 15?

Comment: Hi @Eric, if your problem is about an unexpected result when comparing to specific dates, don't you think you should include those dates in your example?

Answer (score 1):

The `DATETIME` values that are being compared are not the `DATETIME` values you think are being compared.  Here's a suggestion...

Run a query like this:

```
SELECT t.wfstarttimestamp 
     , t.wfendtimestamp
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.wfstarttimestamp,t.wfendtimestamp) AS secs
  FROM t
 WHERE ...
 ORDER
    BY ...
 LIMIT ...
```

And post the results from that. We could add demonstrations that show that built-in `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function operates per the documentation. Unless someone has overridden or modified the built-in `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function, that is not where the problem is.

---

```
SELECT t.wfstarttimestamp
     , t.wfendtimestamp
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.wfstarttimestamp,t.wfendtimestamp) AS secs
  FROM (
         SELECT '2019-02-22 10:20:30' + INTERVAL 0 SECOND AS wfstarttimestamp,  '2019-02-22 10:20:45' + INTERVAL 0 SECOND AS wfendtimestamp
         UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-20 02:03:04' + INTERVAL 0 SECOND, '2019-02-21 02:58:38' + INTERVAL 0 SECOND
       ) t
```

returns:

```
wfstarttimestamp     wfendtimestamp         secs  
-------------------  -------------------  ------
2019-02-22 10:20:30  2019-02-22 10:20:45      15
2019-02-20 02:03:04  2019-02-21 02:58:38   89734
```